# PHP, string of keys access values

Tags: php, string, multidimensional-array

Pulling my hair out with this one, please help

I have an array `$address`

```
$access=sprintf("['results'][1]['address_components'][1]['long_name']");
```

I want to be able be able get data from array using the string i.e

```
$home=$address[$access]
```

Still having probs

```
print_r($address['results'][1]['address_components'][1]);

$key=sprintf("[results][1][address_components][1][long_name]");

printf("key=%s\n", $key);

$home = eval($address . $key);

exit;
```

--- Returns

```
Array
(
    [long_name] => High St
    [short_name] => A4151
    [types] => Array
        (
            [0] => route
        )

)


key=[results][1][address_components][1][long_name]

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting '(' in /media/www.h.com.dev/postCode/post.php(72) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to `sprintf` that string?

Comment: print_r($access) to get some more information and output that information over here also??

Comment: sprintf, Just old programming from my C days

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any user-provided input in `$access`, you can safely use [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval)...

```
$home = eval("return \$address{$access}");
```

Note that when doing an [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval), you are passing code as a string. Therefore, you need  to ensure that `$address` is passed as an actual string, not as a variable (use single quotes `'` or escape the dollar sign `\$` in the double-quoted string); as for `$access`, you want that to be parsed as code so simply concatenate it.

---

If you do have user-provided input, you have to parse `$access`. You can parse `$access` using [`token_get_all()`](http://php.net/token_get_all).

```
function array_get_node($array, $nodePath) {
  $nodePath = '<?php ' . $nodePath;

  $tokens = token_get_all($nodePath);
  array_shift($tokens);

  $current = $array;
  $moved = false;

  var_dump($tokens);

  $tokCount = count($tokens);
  for($i = 0; $i < $tokCount; $i++) {
    if($tokens[$i] === '[' && isset($tokens[$i+2])
       && $tokens[$i+2] === ']' && is_array($tokens[$i+1])) {

      $node = null;
      switch($tokens[$i+1][0]) {
        case T_LNUMBER:
          $node = (int) $tokens[$i+1][1];
          break;

        case T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING:
          $node = preg_replace('#^[\'"](.*)[\'"]$#', '\1', $tokens[$i+1][1]);
          break;

        case T_STRING:
          $node = $tokens[$i+1][1];
          break;            

        default:
          return null;
          break;
      }

      if(!isset($current[$node])) return null;

      $current = &$current[$node];
      $moved = true;
      $i+=2;
    }
  }

  if($moved)
    return $current;

  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you trust $access you could use `eval`. If not, you have to parse $access...